# VFH and heap corruption

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, heap-corruption

I am currently working on point clouds, and I try to create a VFH histogram. Thus I am collecting datas from the camera, filling the point cloud, then creating the normals, and I finally compute my vfh.
All of this is in a loop, and everything works fine, but only once. As soon as I get in the loop for the second time, I encounter the following error message :

"Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Showimage1_2.exe.
This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in Showimage1_2.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded."

To solve itm I have tried to use an application that is supposed to detect those errors "Application verifier", and I am getting the following output : 
"VERIFIER STOP 00000006: pid 0x1958: Corrupted heap pointer or using wrong heap.

```
0CC41000 : Heap handle used in the call.
176F7AF0 : Heap block involved in the operation.
0000050B : Size of the heap block.
0B891000 : Heap where block was originally allocated.
```

Is it possible to locate the error with this output, and how ?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards,

Hinkel

PS : Here is the part of the loop which is apparently corrupting the heap :

```
    // Process to get the normals
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Create the normal estimation class, and pass the input dataset to it

    pcl::NormalEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal> ne;
    ne.setInputCloud (cloud);

    // Create an empty kdtree representation, and pass it to the normal estimation object.
    // Its content will be filled inside the object, based on the given input dataset (as no other search surface is given).

    pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr tree ; 
    ne.setSearchMethod (tree);

    // Output datasets

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);

    // Use all neighbors in a sphere of radius 1cm

    ne.setRadiusSearch (0.01);
    std::cout << "cloud_normals starts to be created..." << std::endl;

    // Compute the features

    ne.compute (*cloud_normals);



    std::cout << "cloud_normals created..." << std::endl;


    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // Process to get VFH

    // Create the VFH estimation class, and pass the input dataset+normals to it

    pcl::VFHEstimation<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::Normal, pcl::VFHSignature308> vfh;
    vfh.setInputCloud (cloud);
    vfh.setInputNormals (cloud_normals);

    // alternatively, if cloud is of type PointNormal, do vfh.setInputNormals (cloud);

    // Create an empty kdtree representation, and pass it to the FPFH estimation object.
    // Its content will be filled inside the object, based on the given input dataset (as no other search surface is given).

    vfh.setSearchMethod (tree);

    // Output datasets

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::VFHSignature308>::Ptr vfhs (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::VFHSignature308> ());

    std::cout << "vfh starts to be created..." << std::endl;
    // Compute the features

    vfh.compute (*vfhs);

    std::cout << "vfh created..." << std::endl;
```

Comment: How do you initialize `tree`? If this is your actual code, you are calling `ne.setSearchMethod` with a `null` shared_ptr.

Comment: Actually I had initialized it in the first place like that : 
(new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZ> ()). But I had also a heap corruption at the same moment, even without the VFH part.
When I remove this initialization, the loop is running without the VFH part, but crashes with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just resolved this issue myself.

When you compile PCL, ensure you have the cmake options:

```
PCL_NO_PRECOMPILE
```

and

```
PCL_ONLY_CORE_POINT_TYPES
```

enabled.

By default they are not, and compiling in this way will yield heap corruptions when the VFH modules are used.

Also disable MSVC_CODE_LINK_OPTIMIZATION, or your libraries will be huge.